# How Do I Make Large Quotation Marks Wrap Properly Around Quotations?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div with a short testimonial inside. Structure as follows:

```
<div id="testimonial">This is a testimonial.<br>A Multi-line testimonial.<br>With at least 3 lines.</div>
```

I want to wrap the testimonial in quotation marks, and size and color everything, so I've added the following CSS:

```
#testimonial {
  font-size: 1.125rem; color: #434343;
}
#testimonial::before, #testimonial::after {
  content: '“'; font-size: 3rem; line-height: 1rem; height: 1rem; color: #c9c8c8;
};
```

The problem is, even though I've applied both a line-height and a height rule to the quotation marks, they remain much larger than the lines of the testimonial itself, thus messing up the look and the lines of the testimonial.

Here's a codepen to demonstrate what's happening:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxxZPE

How do I make it so that the large quotation marks take up the same vertical height as the testimonial text, so it looks neat, not messy?

Comment: Your Codepen-example is just one div with the word "cow" inside it?

Comment: That was an accident. should be fixed now.

Comment: perhaps this doesn't fully answer your question, but this at least looks a little better to me: http://codepen.io/belowthebenthic/pen/myyWvN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem is actually 2 issues in one.

First: the line-height on the quotation marks affects the line height of the last line of the testimonial. As such, the line height for the " should be minimized here (I fixed it by setting line-height for the quotations to 1px).

Second: because the quotations are superscripted, it doesn't really matter what the line-height is, the quotation marks will always be too high up. The best way to resolve this appears to be to set position relative on the pseudo-elements ::before and ::after, and move them down 20 or so pixels.

Here's the updated CSS for the pseudo elements:

```
#testimonial::before, #testimonial::after {
  content: '"'; font-size: 3rem; line-height: 1px; position: relative; 
  bottom: -20px; color: #c9c8c8;
};
```

See codepen demonstration here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBBJLG